# Iterate over non-sequentially named text boxes

Tags: vb.net, telerik

I have 44 text boxes on a screen (to be precise, RadNumericTextBoxes but that's not germane). They follow a common naming pattern (rntb_[NameOfDBField]) which can't be programmatically replicated.

How can I set `.Value` to `Nothing` for each control which has a name ^= rntb_? I have attempted the following:

```
Private Sub ClearValues()
    For Each c as Control in Controls
        If TypeOf c Is RadNumericTextBox Then
            TryCast(c, RadNumericTextBox).Value = Nothing
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

However, Controls.Count = 1 and contains just the name of the master page.

Do I need to pass an argument to Controls, or do I need to do something else altogether? It's "only" 44 text boxes so I could clear each one manually but I'd rather do it programmatically if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the RadNumericTextBoxes are on the Form and not in a container, then something along the lines of

```
Private Sub ClearValues()
    For Each c As Control In Me.Controls
        If TypeOf c Is RadNumericTextBox Then
            Dim rntb = DirectCast(c, RadNumericTextBox)
            If rntb.Name.StartsWith("rntb_") Then
                rntb.Value = Nothing
            End If
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

But if they are in, say, GroupBox1 then you would replace `Me.Controls` in the above with `GroupBox1.Controls`.

And what is the `End For` in your code? A For..Next loop has `Next` at the end of its body in VB.NET.

Comment: Sorry, was a typo (wasn't a direct copy & paste); I've corrected it. Your example returns the same thing, and Me.Controls.Count = 1

Comment: @pcopley Are the RNTBs inside a container control, like a GroupBox or a Panel? someControl.Controls only returns the direct descendant controls of someControl.